# Get List from rest api

Tags: java, spring-rest

I want to get timezones from rest api as list. I tried this:

```
@GetMapping("timezone")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTimezone() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(timezoneService.getTimezoneList().entrySet().stream()
                .map(g -> new AcquirerTimezoneDTO(g.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class AcquirerTimezoneDTO {

    private String timezone;

    public AcquirerTimezoneDTO(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TimezoneService {

    public List<String> getTimezoneList() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  

        String[] allTimeZones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        Arrays.sort(allTimeZones);

        for (int i = 0; i < allTimeZones.length; i++) {
            list.add(allTimeZones[i]);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

But I get error for `.entrySet()` The method entrySet() is undefined for the type List

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`entrySet()` is a method that `Maps` have, not `Lists`.

Just use the `stream()` method directly on the list, without `entrySet()`,like this:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(timezoneService.getTimezoneList().stream()
                .map(g -> new AcquirerTimezoneDTO(g.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: I get The method getKey() is undefined for the type String

Comment: @PeterPenzov Change it to `.map(AcquirerTimezoneDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList()))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change api call from `timezoneService.getTimezoneList().entrySet().stream()` to `timezoneService.getTimezoneList().stream()`.

List's api doesn't have `entrySet()`

Comment: I get The method getKey() is undefined for the type String

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stream directly on the List:

```
@GetMapping("timezone")
public ResponseEntity<?> getTimezone() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(timezoneService.getTimezoneList().stream()
            .map(g -> new AcquirerTimezoneDTO(g.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Also, the List interface doesn't include the `entrySet` method so that's why it chrashes.

Comment: I get The method getKey() is undefined for the type String

Comment: @PeterPenzov because a String object doesn't jave a `getKey()` method

Comment: What should I use. I don't have getTimezone()

Comment: @PeterPenzov The same as before. Remove `getKey()` because you are already working with the String.